# Unity how to Create Texts via script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, canvas

I'm trying to create Texts via script. I want to create texts with the name of objects of a certain tag.

"For example, if I have two objects named Cube and Sphere and both have a tag of "TargetObj" then their names should be displayed as texts on the screen(in the case Cube, Sphere)"

I want to achieve this regardless of the number of objects. so a loop is needed.

Here is what I've tried so far.

```
[SerializeField] GameObject LevelCanvas; 
       targetObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("TargetObj");
            foreach (var obj in targetObjects)
            {
              
               Text mytext = LevelCanvas.AddComponent<Text>();
                 mytext.text = "Find " + obj.name;
                 Font ArialFont = (Font)Resources.GetBuiltinResource(typeof(Font), "Arial.ttf");
                 mytext.font = ArialFont;
                 mytext.material = ArialFont.material;    
            }
```

it only shows one object name although I have 2 more objects that were supposed to be shown as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a text object on a new gameobject.

```
static Text CreateText(Transform parent)
{
    var go = new GameObject();
    go.transform.parent = parent;
    var text = go.AddComponent<Text>();
    return text;
}
```

```
var mytext = CreateText(LevelCanvas.transform);
myext.text = ...
```

Comment: The last two lines are the ones that should be inside the loop right? I tested your code, but nothing is displayed on the screen

Comment: Are there anything created in the hierarchy window?

Comment: Yes, Inside my canvas three gameObjects are created, I have three objects which is good. but the texts are not shown

Comment: Are they inside the display rectange? A new gameobject is created at the left bottom corner of the canvas.

Comment: When I run the game, I can see in the Scene window that there is something at the left bottom but how can I change the position? I can't control them because when I stop the game they disappear

Comment: Change [`mytext.rectTransform.anchoredPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html).

Comment: I tried changing the position and still doesn't show text. I figured out that I forgot to set the font so it was set to none by default. This was the issue. Thank you so much I have been trying to do this for three days.

Comment: I still have one small issue. I would appreciate it if you could help. How can I add /n after each object name? I want them to be displayed each object in a line. but I can't simply add "/n" because it will be used only once.

Comment: currently all objects names are overlapping

Comment: They are overlapping because they have the same position. Didn't you have changed the position for each Text?

Comment: oh no I didn't. I set the location inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Many components in unity can only be added once per game object. That means you need a separate game object for every text you want to show.
A typical way to approach this is to create a "prefab" of a game object which has a text element already. This way you can set a default font and other settings.

Then in code you use the Instantiate method on that prefab and via GetComponent() you can access the text component instance to set the desired string to display.